# Getting error Maximum call stack size exceeded at place-order button click

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.1.7, place-order

When I am trying to place an order I am getting an error like `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` at one-page checkout place order button click

```
Pre Conditions
```

1) One-page chceckout extension (https://marketplace.magento.com/espl-onepagecheckout.html)

2) Webkul Stripe extension (https://store.webkul.com/magento2-marketplace-stripe-vendor-payment.html)

Also getting the same error after disable ESPL one-page checkout extension

```
    Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:247)
    at jQuery.fn.init.find (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:381)
    at jQuery.fn.init (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:387)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (eval at require.load (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:175), <anonymous>:29:16)
    at jQuery (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:206)
    at UiClass.getData (eval at require.load (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:175), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at UiClass.address [as selectPaymentMethod] (eval at require.load (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:175), <anonymous>:9:218)
    at HTMLInputElement.eval (eval at require.load (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:175), <anonymous>:360:164)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:499)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (184add52e34e0cecaf06d4f72a2a5050.min.js:472)
```

[image]
I have also checked var/log folder but not cleared why this error comes

Please give me any solution if anyone faced/knew this issue.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What version do you use of Webkul Stripe?  On 2.0.3 it was fixed one issue with js.

Comment: Hi @BartZalas Webkul Stripe extension version number is 2.0.3, but it was working with the default checkout, but not working now Any suggestions how to debug it?

Comment: Check your module, its going infinity loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually happens due to infinite recursion:

> Infinite recursion is a special case of an infinite loop that is
>   caused by recursion.

This post describes what you should do in detail.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

You should also look into this also from same post;

> You can sometimes get this if you accidentally import/embed the same
>   JS file twice, worth checking in your resources tab of the inspector
>   :)